# Clone an html element one too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, clone

I am attempting to clone an HTML `<select>` dropdown one to many times, given a json response.

The issue is that when I attempt to store the clone in a variable and display it on the screen all I see is the following:

```
[object Object]
```

I made a simple [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/o9sn60bk/) to help explain my issue.

Things to note:

The select dropdown is in a hidden div.

```
<div class="hidden">
    <select class="certList">
       .....
    </select>
</div>
```

I am building a string using:

```
buildList += "<div....
```

I then append the list I build using the jQuery append function.

```
$("#certRow").append(buildList);
```

Lastly if there are any tips to how I should display the results better I am all ears. I was thinking on using an unordered list but wasn't sure how to.

Comment: have you tried `var certList = $(".certList").html();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the html into your append string:

```
"<div class='col-4'>"+certList[0].outerHTML+"</div></div>";
```

As it stands your concatenating a string with the jQuery object (And `object.ToString()` is `[object Object]`)

Comment: but that would only output the options, not the select tag itself

Answer (score 0):

append the element to the div

```
    var certList = $(".certList").clone();
    var buildList = "";
      $.each(res.data, function(i, data) { 
        buildList += "<div class='ti-row'>"+
            "<div class='col-4 center'>"+data +"</div>"+
            "<div class='col-4 right'>Select Certs : </div>"+
            "<div class='col-4 addSelect'></div></div>";
        });
        var html = $(buildList);
        html.find(".addSelect").append(certList);    
        $("#certRow").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `outerHTML`

```
var certList = $(".certList")[0].outerHTML;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9sn60bk/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Use .parent().html() instead of .clone()

clone returns object and you can't append object to string but html returns string that you can append

Comment: And that will cause a different problem. You will not have the select element.

Comment: @epascarello What problem would it cause if you don't mind to explain?

Comment: `.html()` would only give you the options.